# Firebase security rules, ensure one "array remove" only, and only to userId

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have notification records where there is a text and a list of users (max 10).

```
{text: "Beware of the dog", users: [ uid1, uid2, uid3, ... ]}
```

When a user read/acknowledge the notification, I want to remove him from the list of users who can see the notification (then he won't get any anymore).

For that, when the user press the "hide notification button", he send a request to update the notification record with:

```
users: FieldValue.arrayRemove(uid)
```

I want to enfore with security rules that the user:

- Doesn't change other part of the notification record.
- Send its uid and only its uid in the arrayRemove part.

Tried with

```
allow update: if 
    request.auth.uid != null 
    && request.auth.uid in resource.data.users 
    && request.resource.size() == 1 
    && request.resource.data.users != null;
```

- The request.resource.size == 1 doesn't work. Can't figure out why as I have only one field in my request.
- I have no way to ensure the arrayRemove is strictly limited to its uid.

Any hint, help, idea well appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a similar situation and it was quite a brain teaser.
This is what did the trick for me:

```
allow update: if 
    request.auth.uid != null 
    && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly([data])
    && request.resource.data.users.size() == resource.data.users.size() - 1
    && resource.data.users.removeAll(request.resource.data.users)[0] == request.auth.uid
```

Specifically:

1. The first rule is the one you had - checks for user authentication
2. The second rule checks the difference between the new and the old document and makes sure that the only key affected is the one named `data`
3. The third rule makes sure that the new array is exactly 1 item shorter than the old one (so that only 1 item can be removed at a time)
4. The fourth rule *subtracts* the new array (now reduced by 1 `uid`) from the old one with `removeAll()` and returns an array with their difference. In this case, it returns an array which contains only the single `uid` that you chose to `arrayRemove()`. Then we simply check that `uid` - which can only exist at position `[0]` - and make sure it is equal to the `uid` of the authenticated user.

Comment: shouldn't your 3rd rule be just `request.resource.data.users.size() == 1` because there should only be one item in the request?

Comment: ah! looks like `FieldValue.arrayUnion/FieldValue.arrayRemove` does some magic to the `request.resource.data` before validation occurs. Looks like it has all previous values. Your #3 makes total sense now. Thank you

Comment: The second line should be request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['users'])

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without a loop, which doesn't exist in security rules. Well: if you know all users, you might be able to enumerate all options, essentially unfolding the impossible loop. But even if this is possible in security rules, the rules are going to be incredibly verbose.

I'd recommend creating a subcollection where each UID is stored in a separate document. In that subcollection you can then implement your requirement by only allowing the user to only delete their own document.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. I guess Firestore will evolve and provide a solution to this at some point.