# See Array Changes in Firestore Security

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

I have a collection `reviews` where each review contains a list of `uid`s of users who have liked it called `likes`. The schema looks like:

- review (collection)

  - title `string`
  - author `uid`
  - likes [`uid`]
  - posted `timestamp`
- user (collection) - `uid`

  - created `timestamp`
  - email `string`

Currently, I'm handling a user liking a review with:

```
    firebase.firestore().doc(rid).update({
      likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.fetchCurrentUID())
    });
```

And unliking with:

```
    firebase.firestore().doc(rid).update({
      likes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(this.fetchCurrentUID())
    });
```

I only want to let a user add or remove their own `uid` from `likes`.

How can I write a security rule to ensure this? Specifically, I need to see *how* the list is being updated, for instance something like:

```
let newVals = request.resource.data.new_values // or something
return (newVals.length == 1 && newVals[0] == request.auth.uid)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific.  Show the specific client requests that you're using, and the document structures you're working with, as well as more complete security rules that you've already tried and aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson done! However I'm not sure what  you mean by "security rules that you've already tried and aren't working the way you expect," as in this case I have a specific action I don't know how to do.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's expected that you make an attempt at solving the problem, which helps clarify what you're trying to do, and how you're thinking about a possible solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson please explain where I could do a better job of "solving the problem," or ask what you still don't understand. One could potentially iterate through every value in the new and old arrays and see where  they differ, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227926/7834942  firestore does not offer iteration in security rules. Firestore security rules are quite inflexible making it difficult to hack together an attempt.

Comment: Hello mate, I'm facing the same issue. I've tried this for arrayUnion, and it's working `allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.likes;` but not for arrayRemove

Comment: I'm trying this for arrayRemove, but no luck: `allow update: if resource.data.likes[request.auth.uid] != null;`

Comment: @Néstor there is a workaround for this where you put all relations in their own collection or sub collection, ie have fields:  user,  user_likes_content _id then rules become easily enforceable for each added element added to a collection. However for an array of size n we will do n DBS reads to fetch the array as opposed to 1.

Comment: I see.. you mean, create a new collection called `user_likes` inside `users` collection, and add a new document for each user using userId as document name? Yeah looks like the unique workaround for this issue :(  The problem is that I'll need to get rid of `arrayRemove/arrayUnion` functions, which are good to avoid duplicated items etc, but well..  Thanks!

Comment: @Néstor You can easily get around this issue if you make the id of the doc the uid. Then if you call UserLikes.doc(uid).set({uid})  it does nothing if the document already exists. I might submit array updates for firestore security rules as a feature request. Without the ability to see changes, secure arrays seem impossible.

Comment: Solved using Cloud Functions! Thanks Mike, from Google's Slack channel.

You just have to create an Array inside a document that only the user in question can edit, and thanks to Cloud Functions create a 'listener'.

When that Array is modified, thanks to Cloud Functions 'listener' you can do what you want, in my case collect what was modified, and add or remove it in any other collection in my db.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the value of the `arrayUnion` we are updating with, we can check the the final result.

`request.resource.data.likes` Is the array AFTER the `arrayUnion` has been applied.

Therefore liking should result in `request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.likes` == true
For unliking we negate it `!(request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.likes)` == true

This is easy because we have access to `request.auth.uid` but in cases where we don't have the supposed value accessible this way. The following answer has a solution:
[Firebase security rules, ensure one "array remove" only, and only to userId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764457/firebase-security-rules-ensure-one-array-remove-only-and-only-to-userid)

It uses the following trick - create an array intersection with `removeAll`:

`resource.data.likes.removeAll(request.resource.data.likes)[0] == request.auth.uid`